# display hidden form when specific number of integers/characters are entered into a text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a function where when a specific number of integers (eg. a phone number) are entered into a text field, a hidden form is displayed and both initial text field and form re-positioned.

Any examples available on how this can be accomplished?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick sample

HMTL

```
<input type="text" id="textfield"/>
<div id="hidden_container">
I'm in a hidden container
</div>
```

CSS

```
#hidden_container{
  display:none;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$('#textfield').on('input', function(){
  if($('#textfield').val().length > 2){
    $('#hidden_container').show();
  }
  else{
    $('#hidden_container').hide();
  }
});
```

[A CodePen Sandbox](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xZXVXW)

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".input1").keyup(function (e) {
            var szdata = $(this).val();
            var patt = /^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/g; //"1234-456-8888"
            var result = patt.test(szdata);
            if (result == true) {
                $('#form_test').css('display', "")
            }

            else {
                $('#form_test').css('display', "none")
            }
        });
    });





 <input type="text" class="input1"/>
  <form id="form_test" style="display:none">
     name: <input  type="text"/>
  </form>
```